# How to update embedded arrays with Horizon?

Tags: angular, rethinkdb, horizon

What is an example of implementing embedded arrays with Horizon? So if the model were something like this:

```
{
  "$hz_v$": 9 ,
  "id":  "u012345" ,
  "userName": "Productive Joe",
  "todos": [
     {
       "id": "t012345",
       "text" : "First TODO",
       "date": "Thu Mar 23 2017 23:30:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
     },
     {
       "id": "t012346",
       "text" : "Second TODO",
       "date": "Fri Mar 24 2017 13:46:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
     },

  ]
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to update elements to the `"todos"` array. Say (1) if I have matching todos id, I want to update the todo and if not (2) push the new todo to the "todos" array.

My first thought was to try `find(id)` and `upsert()`, but I can't figure out the correct implementation.

Comment: when you want to update during display or posting to server?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `array.push()` and then use the lodash uniq to remove duplicate: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq